# “...Which I have a basic knowledge of”

Tags: idioms, prepositions

> Russian, which I have a basic knowledge of

Is the entire phrase *which I have a basic knowledge of* idiomatic in English? Or is it just an Italian phrase construction I inadvertently transposed into English? I did some research on Google and it seems only non-native speakers used this very phrase.

Comment: It appears that also native speakers use this expression. Have a basic knowledge of: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+a+basic+knowledge+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20basic%20knowledge%20of%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Unfortunately I’m referring to the exact phrase. 'which I’ should be included. While I think ‘have a basic knowledge of’ is fine, I’m oddly not so sure about the whole sentence.

Comment: I can't see what the issue is... are you trying to translate from Italian into English?

Comment: Can you supply the rest of the sentence?

Comment: "Russian, which I have a basic knowledge of"

Comment: @gurghet, it's fine, although "Russian, a language of which I have a basic knowledge", would be more formal style.

Comment: "Russian, which I have a basic knowledge of" is reasonably correct IF "which I have a basic knowledge of" is a parenthetical statement (to be followed, presumably, by some statement about Russian).  It's not correct as a sentence by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your phrase

> which I have a basic knowledge of

is grammatical and sounds fine.

You are ending that phrase with a preposition, though, which some people frown on (or, on which some people frown). If you want to avoid that construction,

> of which I have a basic knowledge

might sound better in written language. In spoken language, which is much less formal, your phrase is fine.

Comment: I cannot explain why, but the article bugs me here. I have no problem with saying, “I have a basic knowledge of Russian” (apart from the fact that it's a lie), but when Russian is removed from the clause that's made relative, the article must go for some reason: “Russian, of which I have (some) basic knowledge”. It just doesn't sound right to me with the article there…

Comment: That's interesting, truly, because I feel oddly uncomfortable *without* the article. I don't know if this is AmE, of if it's a softening-word usage... I would substitute *some* for *basic* in your example. Can't explain it either.

Comment: I’m not entirely happy with the sentence without the article either, but less unhappy with that than with the version with the article. But I definitely agree: I’d add _some_ in any case, just to avoid the awkwardness of article/no-article entirely. “Some (basic/working) knowledge” works whether the following prepositional phrase is removed or not.

Answer (score 0):

As written, it is a non-sentence: no verb. Essentially, what you have here is a subject, followed by a subordinate clause needing a closing comma, both of which are lusting for a predicate to arrive and provide independence. :-)

The *no ending preposition* rule has pretty much been tossed aside now.